# Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade and web app do not work

Tags: webapps

I started Firefox, saw the pop-up window and clicked install for Gmail and Google calendar. I get no change in my unity left launcher menu, nor when I tried to type Gmail in the dash.

However when I tried to uninstall the Amazon webapp in the Ubuntu Software Package, it says that I first need to uninstall Gmail and Google calendar. I don't really see why but at least it means that they are somewhere.

When I do

```
sudo apt-cache search gmail
```

I get

```
unity-mail - Mail notifications and count for Unity
unity-webapps-gmail - Unity Webapp for GMail
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of people who can't get the web apps to work, and it has already been reported on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webapps-applications/+bug/1068662